# How can I test form submit in React?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs

I have the following React component:

```
export default class SignUpForm extends React.Component {
    ...
    doSignupForm(event) {
        // Some API call...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form action="/" onSubmit={this.doSignupForm.bind(this)} id="register-form">
                    <button type="submit" id="register_button">Sign Up</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

I want to test that the button fires the `doSignupForm` function - how do I do this (ideally using Mocha/Chai/Enzyme/Sinon)?

In addition, as you can see the `doSignupForm` function fires an API call - should  this API call be tested seperately using an integration test (?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/308), event bubbling is not supported in Enzyme. Therefore, found the following workaround:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import chai from 'chai';
var expect = chai.expect;

it('fires form submit', () => {
   const doSignupForm = sinon.stub(SignUpForm.prototype, 'doSignupForm').returns(true);

    const wrapper = mount(<SignUpForm />);
    wrapper.find('#register_button').get(0).click();
    expect(doSignupForm).to.have.been.called;
    doSignupForm.restore();

});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simulate form submission using React Utils:

```
var rendered = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(SignupForm);
var form = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(rendered, 'form');
TestUtils.Simulate.submit(form);
```

Also, testing calls to the actual API is not reliable, you should mock the API call with responses you expect from it, an idea would be to extract the API call in to its own module, and setup an spy to test the behaviour of your component with an specific response (example spy with Jasmine):

```
spyOn(apiModule, "requestProjects").and.callFake(function() {
    return { ...someProjects };
});
```

Reference:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html
https://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2014/12/10/Mocking-calls-with-Jasmine

Comment: Whay are testing calls to the API unreliable?

Comment: It's because when interacting with external services, you normally don't own that code. If your internet connection or the service is down your test suite would fail, even if your code is fine. Another factor is that it's very slow. You want to test the behaviour of your code under controlled conditions.

Comment: In my case, the API is the API of my own application. That aside, how can you ever test an API, i.e. the vendor could change the API and your tests would still be passing because they have been isolated (?)

Comment: The idea is that you can abstract the API from your application so that any change to the API doesn't affect your components directly. Instead of making the ajax requests inside your component, create a separated module for managing all the requests your app needs, and do the ajax requests only inside of that module. This way, when testing your components you can mock the methods in your module and return controlled data. You won't want to test your components agains't the actual api, because as I mentioned, It's unreliable. You can still do integration tests for that specific module.

Comment: But what I want to express is that your frontend client shouldn't depend on your backend to be working in order for it to work. They should be as isolated as possible. If you do testing correctly in your backend aswell, then you won't have any issues connecting the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using `Enzyme` and `Sinon`

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import expect from 'expect';

it('fires form submit', () => {
   const doSignupForm = sinon.stub(SignUpForm.prototype, 'doSignupForm').returns(true);

    const wrapper = mount(<SignUpForm />);
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(doSignupForm.called).to.be.true;
    doSignupForm.restore();



});
```

Comment: Any comment about how to test the API call too?

Comment: This does not capture the onSubmit action of the form.