# How to properly unit test login and local storage

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

After 3 days researching and not ariving anywhere, I decided to ask here for someone that already have similar experience or can point a better path to follow.

The better SO question I've found was this but left some questions in air: [React - how to test form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638384/react-how-to-test-form-submit)

Since I'm begginer I believe I may getting something wrong, but no sure exactly which. If it's the way I build the components or even test concept itself.

---

I have the following case:

- When a user logins in, it calls API (mock) then save token result (when successful) to localStorage (mock)
- When user is already logged in, it gets redirected to homepage

My code until now:

**Login Component**

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.sendLoginRequest(this.state).then(
            ({data}) => {
                console.log(data);
            },
            (data) => {
                console.error(data);
            }
        );
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

render() {
        return (
            <div id='auth-container' className='login'>               
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                <FormGroup controlId='emailaddress'>
                    <InputGroup bsSize='large'>
                    <InputGroup.Addon>
                        <Icon glyph='icon-fontello-mail' />
                    </InputGroup.Addon>
                    <FormControl 
                        autoFocus
                        className='border-focus-blue'  
                        type='email'                                                     
                        placeholder='email@fixdin.com'
                        name='email'
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={this.state.email} />
                    </InputGroup>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId='password'>
                    <InputGroup bsSize='large'>
                    <InputGroup.Addon>
                        <Icon glyph='icon-fontello-key' />
                    </InputGroup.Addon>
                    <FormControl 
                        className='border-focus-blue' 
                        type='password' 
                        placeholder='password' 
                        name='password' 
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={this.state.password} />
                    </InputGroup>
                </FormGroup>
            </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Login.propTypes = {
    sendLoginRequest: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

**authAction.js**

```
import createApi from '../services/api';
import { saveToken } from '../services/session';

export function sendLoginRequest(loginData) {
  return dispatch => {
    const api = createApi();
    const loginPromise = api.post('auth/', loginData);

    loginPromise.then(
      ({ data }) => {
        saveToken(data.token);
      }
    );

    return loginPromise;
  }
}
```

**API..js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { isAuthenticated, getToken } from './session';

export const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/';

export default function createAPI() {
    let auth = { }
    if (isAuthenticated()) {
        auth = {
            Token: getToken()
        }
    }

    return axios.create({
       baseURL: BASE_URL,
       auth: auth
    });
};
```

**session.js**

```
const TOKEN_KEY = 'token';

export function saveToken(value)
{
    localStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, value);
}

export function getToken()
{
    return localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)
}

export function isAuthenticated() {
    return getToken() !== null;
}
```

My test stack is Mocha/Chai/Enzyme/sinon and it's defined

**setup.js**

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

class LocalStorageMock { 
  constructor() { 
    this.store = {}; 
  } 

  clear() { 
    this.store = {}; 
  } 

  getItem(key) { 
    return this.store[key]; 
  } 

  setItem(key, value) { 
    this.store[key] = value.toString(); 
  } 
}; 

if(!global.document) {
  global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
  global.window = document.defaultView;
  global.navigator = {userAgent: 'node.js'};
  global.localStorage = new LocalStorageMock; 
}
```

**login-test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios'
import moxios from 'moxios'

import store from './../src/store';
import LoginPage from './../src/auth/components/Login';

describe('Login', () => {
    beforeEach(function () {
      moxios.install(axios)
    })

    afterEach(function () {
      moxios.uninstall(axios)
    })

    it('should call action on form submit', () => {
        const submitRequest = sinon.stub(LoginPage.prototype, 'handleSubmit').returns(true);

        const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><LoginPage /></Provider>);
        wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');
        expect(submitRequest.called).to.be.true;

        submitRequest.restore();
    });

    it('should save token on succesfull login', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><LoginPage /></Provider>);
        const emailInput = wrapper.find('input[type="email"]');
        const passInput =  wrapper.find('input[type="password"]');
        const form = wrapper.find('form');

        emailInput.value = "valid@email.com";
        passInput.value = '123456789';
        form.simulate('submit'); // Should I use submit button instead???

        moxios.wait(function () {
        let request = moxios.requests.mostRecent()

            request.respondWith({
            status: 200,
            response:
                { Token: 'validToken' }          
            }).then(function () {
                expect(localStorage.getItem('Token')).to.equal('validToken');
            });
        });        
    });
});
```

**Above test does not pass**, since it returns false for `submitRequest.called` and second test fails with error `"Cannot read property 'respondWith' of undefined"`. I'm not sure how to fix and more, I'm not sure if I idealized it right!!

When doing a lot of research about it, I've seen examples with tests specific for component method call + isolated action test.
So...

1. When I think about "click login and save token" I'm overthinking a unit test? There's a better way to test things like that? Maybe separate some concerns?
2. This is the correctly way to test if a form submit invoke its callback? If so, why sinon is not working there?
3. This is the correctly way to mock + test api call to login and localStorage? If so, why Moxios is not working properly? It keeps giving me that `mostRecent()` is undefined.
4. If no, to question 2 and 3, where can I find a valid and working example of how to properly test cited behavior?

Thanks in advance.